# Which format in office libre writer to choose in order to omit problems when opening in word on windows ?

Tags: windows, libreoffice, microsoft-word

I have written a document in Libre Office Writer, 
it is crucial to me to keep the documents format.
Now I am clueless in which format to save it, since there is
a plethora of options, even different formats for windows.

Comment: I'm not sure you can guarantee it, from my experience. But .doc and .docx would be the closest, definitely not rtf. However, a pdf would be guaranteed to be consistent, use that if you can

Answer (score 1):

If your MS Word is version 2007 or above then choose `.docx` type. If not, then choose `.doc` type.